# Ajax and React functions

Tags: ajax, function, reactjs

I have this ajaxify form which submits the data well, however I want to pass data from this ajax code to a React component to update the view after successfully submitting the data. How do I pass some data to React using a function?

When using the code below it gives me 'unidentified function', how can make it accessible to both ajax and React?

```
$('#upload').ajaxForm({
  success: function(data) {
    newlocal(data);
  }
});
```

And this is the React code I use:

```
var Postlist = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {posts: []};
  },
  newLocal : function(data){
    alert(data);
  },
```

Comment: initialize "data" in ajax call.

Comment: can you provide a code ?@RaviChhatrala

Comment: Have a look at the tutorial: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html, and the docs for ReactJS . They have examples of patterns for using Ajax.  You can't call `newLocal` directly as it's a function on the `PostList` class. You'd need to minimally refer to a specific instance of it. As you haven't posted enough of your code, I can't suggest what instance variable would be used though.

Answer (score 1):

The callback that you are passing to the ajaxForm should do a setState. I assume you have your form component to which can pass props like below. Since you are accessing the actual DOM element, in this case `#upload`, it can be done only with componentDidMount.

```
var PostList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      posts: []
    };
  },

  _handleSubmitSuccess: function(httpStatus, createdPost) {
    var that = this;
    that.setState({posts: (that.state.posts << createdPost)});
  },

  posts: function() {
    this.state.posts.map(function(post) {
      return (
        <div>
        ...
        </div>
      );
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.posts()}

        <br />

        <PostForm onSubmitSuccess={this._handleSubmitSuccess} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var PostForm = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var that = this;

    $('#upload').ajaxForm({
      success: that.props.onSubmitSuccess
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <form id="#upload">
      ...
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Hope you get the idea.